# Best way to administrate web-app?

Tags: mysql, web-server

i'm looking for the best and safest way to administrate my mysql-databases etc. on my server. any advice on this?

thanks

Comment: This question is too vague for anyone to really help you, so my initial advice is to revise your question to be more specific (What are you managing, what are your requirements, etc.) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few recommendations I can give you:

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

> phpMyAdmin is a free software tool
>   written in PHP intended to handle the
>   administration of MySQL over the World
>   Wide Web. phpMyAdmin supports a wide
>   range of operations with MySQL. The
>   most frequently used operations are
>   supported by the user interface
>   (managing databases, tables, fields,
>   relations, indexes, users,
>   permissions, etc), while you still
>   have the ability to directly execute
>   any SQL statement.

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)

> Webmin is a web-based interface for
>   system administration for Unix. Using
>   any modern web browser, you can setup
>   user accounts, Apache, DNS, file
>   sharing and much more. Webmin removes
>   the need to manually edit Unix
>   configuration files like /etc/passwd,
>   and lets you manage a system from the
>   console or remotely.

[MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/)

> MySQL Workbench is a cross-platform,
>   visual database design tool developed
>   by MySQL. It is the highly anticipated
>   successor application of the
>   DBDesigner4 project. MySQL Workbench
>   is available as a native GUI tool on
>   Windows, Linux and OS X in different
>   editions.

[Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)

> Navicat for MySQL is a powerful
>   Database administration and
>   development tool for MySQL. It works
>   with any MySQL Database Server from
>   version 3.21 or above, and supports
>   most of the latest MySQL features
>   including Trigger, Stored Procedure,
>   Function, Event, View, and Manage
>   User, etc.
>
> Features in Navicat are sophisticated
>   enough to provide professional
>   developers for all their specific
>   needs, yet easy to learn for users who
>   are new to MySQL.
>
> With Navicat well-designed Graphical
>   User Interface (GUI), Navicat for
>   MySQL lets you quickly and easily
>   create, organize, access and share
>   information in a secure and easy way,
>   taking MySQL administration.

Sorry, I could only post two links due to not having enough rep at the moment. Maybe someone can edit this and link MySQL Workbench and Navicat.

Hope this helps!